# How do I get the lat long values from an X, Y pixel position, in a Robinson projected map, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, maps, latitude-longitude, map-projections

I would like to resolve pixel X,Y positions, on a Robinson projected map, to lat longs.

I have a found a JavaScript function that can resolve lat longs to pixels - https://github.com/afar/robinson_projection - but I cannot work out (or find an implementation of) pixels to lat longs.

I have found various articles about how Robinson projection works, such as https://simplemaps.com/flash/robinson-projection-in-as3-gpl/

I'm basically stuck at this point - the maths required to work out lat long from pixel X,Y is well beyond my terrible maths ability - and despite reading these things quite a few times, the logic isn't clear to me either.

I assumed the logic is in the d3-geo or d3-geo-projection source code somewhere, but couldn't find anything when searching through it.

Looking at Wikipedia, there is this:

> Coordinates of points on a map are computed as follows:
> [image: robinson equation]

..but I don't really understand how to put it into Javascript, or work out "the central meridian chosen for the map", and even then are these "coordinates" the same as pixel values?

**Background info**:

I'm trying to make a very lightweight, simple javascript function, that can do lat long to pixel X,Y and vice versa, for both Mercator and Robinson projections - **without using d3 etc**.. I want it to be less then 2kb minified and gzipped, no deps.

I've got Mercator working OK - there's lot of examples. But still struggling with **Robinson** projection.

The full code, if it helps, is here: https://github.com/sc0ttj/component/pull/53

(Side note, which may affect the solution I need:

For some reason I had to change `latSign = getSign(lat)` to `latSign = 0-getSign(lat)` to get the map to show the right way up, vertically - see https://github.com/sc0ttj/component/pull/53/files#diff-dc34d0b1b3b6f92f7c3e71af717cf56a5f98923980b859c128d793991690ebdcR64.)

I'm shamelessly standing on the shoulders of these two projects:

- https://github.com/nunobaldaia/mercatormap
- https://github.com/afar/robinson_projection